# MogoDB - Query has become extremely slow on a PSA replicaset

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-replica-set

I have a MongoDB replica set with one primary, one arbiter, one vote bearing secondary, and two no vote bearing secondary servers.

The two non-vote bearing secondaries are bare metal mongo installs to help with heavy aggregation queries. (each 16cores/128GBRam/SSD)

The replica set member configuration is at the bottom of the question.

The following query is run multiple times a minute (around 100) against different collections (~10).

The query used to take no longer than 2 seconds at worst.

Since about a week ago I have noticed that applications that depend on that query were erroring on timeout. I have run the query against the replica set connection (mongo+srv), or individual members - with the same result - "***timeout***"

I cannot recall any events to have caused the issue and I am wondering if the query might be constructed somehow fundamentally wrong to be causing the issue.

The query is *selecting the least extracted item that has not been deleted and has not been archived.*

I have indexed the fields "*attributes*", "*attributes.deleted*", "*attributes.archieved*", "*last_extracted*" but this has not helped.

The size of the collections is between 2gb/50K records to 10gb/150k records.

**Is there anything wrong with this query?**

```
db.getCollection("threads").aggregate(
    [{'$match': 
            {'$and': 
                [{'$or': 
                    [{'attributes': 
                        {'$exists': false}}, 
                     {'attributes.deleted': 
                            {'$exists': false}}, 
                     {'attributes.deleted': {'$eq': false}}]}, 
                 {'$or': 
                     [{'attributes.archived': 
                         {'$exists': false}}, 
                         {'attributes.archived': 
                             {'$eq': false}}]}
                 ]}}, 
      {'$project': {'_id': 1, 'url': 1, 'last_extraction': 1}}, 
      {'$sort': {'last_extraction': 1}}, 
      {'$limit': 1}
      ])
```

**Replica Set Members Configuration**

```
rs0:SECONDARY> cfg.members
[
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "XXXXXX1:27777",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 0.8,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" : "XXXXX2:27777",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 0.2,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "host" : "XXXXX3:27777",
        "arbiterOnly" : true,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 0,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "host" : "XXXXXX4:27777",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 0,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : 5,
        "host" : "XXXXXXX5:27776",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 0,
        "tags" : {

        },
        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
        "votes" : 0
    }
]
```

Comment: A bit hard to say (at least for me). Try `<query>.explain("executionStats")` to see how much time your queries take and what is the winning plan. Perhaps your indexes are set up incorrectly.